# Connectedness of $\hat{K}_U$.

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain and $K\subset U$ compact. If $K$ is connected then $\hat{K}_U$ is also connected?

$\hat{K}_U= \{z \in U: |f(z)| \leq \sup_K |f|,  \forall f\in \mathcal{O}(U)\}$: holomorphically convex hull of $K$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Should that $\Omega$ be a $U$?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega=U$.